# Finding a string pattern in a string

Tags: python, string

I have this string for example:

```
line = "Hello my name is {{ name }} and I am {{ age }} years old."
```

How do I extract the string pattern `{{ string }}` from `line`?

The result should be `['name', 'age']`

Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Regex. Use the ``re`` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> line = "Hello my name is {{ name }} and I am {{ age }} years old."
>>> findall("{{\s(.*?)\s}}", line)
['name', 'age']
>>>
```

Below is a breakdown of the Regex pattern:

```
{{     # {{
\s     # A space
(.*?)  # A capture group of zero or more characters matched non-greedily
\s     # A space
}}     # }}
```

If you would like more information, all of the Regex syntax used above is explained [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

---

Note that if the length of the whitespace can vary, you may need to replace `\s` with `\s*`, which will match zero or more spaces:

```
>>> from re import findall
>>> line = "Hello my name is {{name          }} and I am {{          age   }} years old."
>>> findall("{{\s*(.*?)\s*}}", line)
['name', 'age']
>>>
```